# Initializing popup outside of the kivy main app class in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy

I am trying to write a function that launches a popup in a kivy gui based on a conditional. The method is outside of the main app because I am using multithreading to have both run at the same time. Every time I try to initialize a new popup in the method which is outside of the main app, it crashes. If I don't initialize it, it runs fine. Any ideas?

Comment: you can only do gui updates in the main thread ...

Comment: How would I initialize a popup and open it based on a second thread then? I can send you my code privately if you could help please.

Comment: Use `Clock.schedule_once()`.

Comment: Hi John, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that. Here is my code. You can see I am instantiating the app and trying to call it in the second thread.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oStyu9PA9ydhwfnXus3V98HqkdmtmD1oODWEsWDmKZw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried to change it where I can access the screenManager of my app where the function is but when I call it, it crashes. I'm doing this through     App.get_running_app().root.open_recognized()

Answer (score 0):

You must perform GUI related operations (like opening or dismissing a `Popup`) on the kivy thread.

In your code, where you would call `sm.open_unrecognized()` do `Clock.schedule_once(sm.open_unrecognized, 0)`. This will schedule the call to `open_unrecognized` on the kivy thread after the next frame is displayed.

Dismissing the `Popup` can be done automatically (any click outside the `Popup`) or explicitly using something like a `Button` in the `Popup`. Note that any code called by a `Button` event is performed on the kivy thread.

See the [Clock documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) for more information